# Is this ODE a well-known and studied one?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I came across this ordinary differential equation
$$x \,(y')^2+a=0\,,$$
where $a$ is a real number, $x$ is a real variable and $y$ is a real algebraic function of $x$. I was wondering whether this is a well-known and studied ODE or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the change of variable $x = t^4$, $y(x) = u(t)$, you find $u$ satisfies Chrystal's equation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

If $a<0$ and $y(x):= 2 \sqrt{-a} \sqrt{x}$, then $y$ is a solution of differential equation on $(0, \infty).$

Comment: thank you for your answer but I was looking for a different one. Maybe I didn't explain well enough in my post. I know what the solutions of this equation are. I was just wondering whether or not it is a special case of a well-known ODE, like the Bernoulli or the Riccati equations.